# Caliburn: how to bind hosted controls to ViewModel properties

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, caliburn.micro, caliburn

I created a control which is hosting two content controls. I would like Caliburn to 
resolve the View/ViewModel for me but Caliburn ignores the hosted/inner ContentControls with the name SignalGenerator (see below). Any idea how to get around that problem?

```
        <cc:HorizontalSplitterLayoutControl >

            <cc:HorizontalSplitterLayoutControl.UpperContent>
                <Label Content="Blockdiagram" />
            </cc:HorizontalSplitterLayoutControl.UpperContent>

            <cc:HorizontalSplitterLayoutControl.LowerContent>

                <ContentControl x:Name="SignalGenerator"/>

            </cc:HorizontalSplitterLayoutControl.LowerContent>
        </cc:HorizontalSplitterLayoutControl>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried myself, but you should be able to do something like the following:

```
<ContentControl x:Name="SignalGenerator" cal:View.Model="{Binding}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In another project I had to do it like this:

```
<ContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding SignalGenerator}" />
```